# Bootstrap navbar dropdown table without dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]How do you create the bootstrap dropdown without the actual button? I want to use this feature somewhere else.

Without bootstrap (from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp):

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I want what you get when you click on the button, but not the button. Bootstrap styling would be a plus.

image from: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h

Comment: Is you want is custom select menu?

Comment: I want the table that is generated when you click on select, but without having to click on select.

Comment: use radio button lol :))

Comment: you mean select options right? Can you please give some image reference or something else which can describe what you want ? Because I didn't get you.

Comment: What he means is.. He wants to trigger the `<select>` dropdown using another button next to it. (without having to click on that same `<select>`). @shell - correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Added image, hopefully it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to trigger the dropdown without manually having to click on it. So you need to make use of `window.onload` in javascript to trigger the dropdown on page load.

I have also taken the liberty to use the Bootstrap dropdown as you wanted.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="dropdown">
    <!-- the id is important here -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function () { 
    $("#dropdown").dropdown('toggle')
};
```

[Updated Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMYvzJ)

Comment: Thank you. I just want to have the dropdown menu. No button at all. See my image.

Comment: Then just remove the `runThis` to `onload`. Simple :-) Check my updated answer.

Comment: Since you are looking for bootstrap dropdown, it is even more simple involving just one line of code in javascript. Please check the updated answer